# Change target to x86 in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, x86, platform

I have a VS2010 solution with several projects in it. These projects are winforms apps and libraries.

Now I MUST change platform for all projects to X86 from any CPU, but I can not do it, in some of my projects it stays 'Any CPU'. In these cases list contains only 'Any CPU'. It is impossible to change it.

What could be the reason of it? How should I fix it?

I read some wild solutions, e.g. open sln file in text editor and replace any cpu strings to X86 etc, but I hope there is a more straightforward and cleaner solution.

Thanks!

VS2010/.net4/c#

Comment: If you have only 'Only CPU', you can use <New> option when chosing platform and create x86 setting, then choose it, does it also fail for some reason?

Comment: Great, I didn't know if I interpreted your question correctly. Glad I could help, I've allowed myself to put it as an asnwer :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have the `Any CPU` option, you can use the `<New>...` option when choosing the platform and create a new platform setting for the x86 platform, and then choose it.

Comment: What if we don't have x86 in the selective list, I only have "x64" and "Itanium"