# ODBC connections in Visual Studio 2022 : Unable to connect to Redshift Cluster

Tags: visual-studio, odbc, amazon-redshift, driver, connection-string

I'm trying to get something very simple to work :-)

The driver is mapped in ODBC x64

[image]

```vb
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Dim odbcconn As New OdbcConnection()

connstr = "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=Redshift-awsuser;Driver={Amazon Redshift (x64)}; Server=gref-cluster-1.yyy.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com; Database=xxx; UID=yyy; PWD=xxx; Port=1234"

odbcconn.ConnectionString = connstr
odbcconn.Open()
```

I've run into the following errors:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application'

Other connection strings I've tried :

```vb
connstr = "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=Redshift-awsuser;Driver={Amazon Redshift (x86)}; Server=gref-cluster-1.yyy.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com; Database=xxx; UID=yyy; PWD=xxx; Port=1234"
```

OR

```vb
connstr = "DSN=Redshift-awsuser;Driver={Amazon Redshift (x86)}; Server=gref-cluster-1.yyy.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com; Database=xxx; UID=yyy; PWD=xxx; Port=1234"
```

OR

```vb
connstr = "DSN=Redshift-awsuser;Server=gref-cluster-1.yyy.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com; Database=xxx; UID=yyy; PWD=xxx; Port=1234"
```

I can connect as a `Dataset`, but not through the `ODBCConnection`. I need the connection to perform a loop function within VS / Visual Basic.

I haven't used Visual Studio in a while so I'm hoping the solution is super simple!

Comment: I can;t find this setting in VS:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395492/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-arc

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot of 32-bit check]

I unchecked the part highlighted "Prefer 32-bit" under the Compile settings. To find this go to Project -> (last menu item) [Application name] properties; then compile settings.

[image: ODBC connection - string]

I also copied the connection string from the Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> Modify Connection -> Connection String field.

Super confused how this started working.